Movie or series involving a red-headed female scientist who invented a device that permits travel to other time periods or parts of the world
It's a movie or series on a streaming service. I feel like it was 2020 or maybe earlier or later.
I specifically can picture two women, one of whom is a red-headed scientist and the other is dark-haired and older than the redhead. They dwell in a black house in Europe and it's probably the 1920s. There is time travel involved or maybe just a portal to different parts of the world. I think it involves a golden sphere that is thrown, expands, and then time travels/portals, or a bike. That could be wrong, but the redhead is the one that invented it, and they harbor like misfits in their community.

So not Idaho Transfer then?

Not time travel, but time viewing; https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11366674/reviews

This is The Nevers (2021).

From HBO's official site for the series:

In the final years of Queen Victoria's reign, London is rocked by a supernatural event that gives certain people--mostly women--abnormal abilities. But no matter their particular "turns," all who belong to this new underclass are in grave danger. It falls to quick-fisted widow Amalia True and brilliant young inventor Penance Adair to protect and shelter these gifted "orphans."

According to the Wikipedia page, it's a 12-episode sci-fi series created by Joss Whedon for HBO, and was cancelled after one season.
The show is set in late 19th-century London and involves some people, mostly women, mysteriously developing superhuman powers. These people come to be known as the Touched or the Afflicted and are viewed by many normal people with fear or suspicion, similar to mutants in Marvel comics and movies.
The protagonists -- Amalia True and Penance Adair -- are members of the Touched themselves, and help to run an orphanage that provides shelter to several other members.
Amalia is an English widow who has dark hair, can handle herself in a fight, and sees glimpses of the future. This is visualised on-screen as her briefly inhabiting the body of her future self, with the environment around her changing if her future self is in a different location, which makes it look like she's briefly being transported to another time period/location.
Penance is a young Irish inventor with reddish-blonde hair who can see energy patterns. Her inventions include flashbang-like grenades, a robot carriage driver and a three-wheeled car.



